# How to select empty string using sp_executesql?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am trying select empty string using sp_executesql. Here is my SQL

```
declare @query nvarchar(MAX)
set @query = 'SELECT '+'\''\'+' AS Name'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @query
```

I want to make select statement like below (normal sql statement), but using sp_executesql

```
SELECT '' AS Name
```

Comment: Escaping `'` is done by doubling it (`''`). T-SQL has no escape character.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Can you give me sample code please. Is it not possible?

Comment: See the marked duplicate.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I didn't get your point. Can you give me more explaination, Thanks

Comment: `declare @query nvarchar(MAX) = 'SELECT '''' AS Name'`...

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer, I hope it will help for someone

declare @query nvarchar(MAX)
set @query = 'SELECT '''' AS Name'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @query